# Proof of a group of order $60$ is simple containing sylow $5$ subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

So I was reading Sylow theorems from Dummit and Foote while I came across the following result[image]

I've understood the whole proof except the highlighted portion in red circle. Why $|H|\geq 1+4\times 6$? I didn't get that. Can anyone explain this to me? May be it is a very stupid question but my brain isn't clicking. Thanks.

Comment: The six Sylow 5-subgroups have trivial intersection (why?), hence if $H$ contains them all, then $H$ has at least $6\cdot 4$ non-trivial elements plus the neutral element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are assuming that the number of Sylow 5-subgroups is not 1, the only possibility (by Sylow's theorem) is that there are 6 such subgroups.  The assumption that $H$ is normal means that $H$ is closed under conjugation, and since all of these Sylow 5-subgroups are conjugates of each other, they must all be in $H$.  They intersect in the identity, so (of course) that must be in $H$.  Then each of these groups has 4 non-identity elements (which must be distinct since they intersect only in the identity) so 6 groups, times 4 non-identity elements each must also be in $H$.  Thus, $H$ must have at least $1 + 4 \cdot 6$ elements, or $|H| \geq 1 + 4 \cdot 6$.